# Android: How to get this layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there a way to get the images touching like in this image without guessing the heights of each horizontal LinearLayout?

[image: Can i do this without guessing the layout heights?]

As you can see from my XML i had to guess the LinearLayout heights at 144dp to get this effect, is there a better way that would work on different screen sizes?

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="144dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_sport" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView02"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_science" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="144dp"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView03"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_science" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView04"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_sport" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout03"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="144dp"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView05"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_sport" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView06"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_science" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

If possible I would prefer to be able to do it in XML. The images are square so they have to fill the width and still be in proportion. I can almost do it with fitXY but that just stretches their width and not their height.

Comment: How are you guessing the height of the linear layout? Do you mean you're guessing the height of what the linear layout will be depending on the heights of the images in them? Can you put each horizontal linear layout in a vertical linear layout and achieve what you want?

Comment: I increased the height of LinearLayout01 until the images perfectly filled the LinearLayout (The linear layout became square)

Comment: @cskoala Using vertical LinearLayouts makes is a good option. It fills the screen vertically with slight gaps between the two vertical LinearLayouts. I can probably compensate for this by using scaleXY

Comment: yeah, you may be able to change the margins to 0. Not sure if that'll get rid of the gaps though. You would have to try it. :)

Comment: @cskoala Its not important that the images are perfectly square so i used scaleType:fitXY on all the images which fills the gaps as you can see from my answer :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Whilst the images aren't perfectly square (although its quite unnoticeable) i managed to solve this problem by using 2 Vertical `LinearLayout`s instead of 3 Horizontal ones and using `ScaleType=fitXY` to fill the remaining gaps, leaving me with this:

[image: Final Layout]

From the code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView03"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_science" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_sport" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView02"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_science" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView04"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_sport" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView03"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_science" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView04"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_sport" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use a GridView instead of many LinearLayouts.

If you want to keep your code, update this :

Your main layout should have this property :

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

The other "Layout Wrappers" should have :

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

Your imageView should have :

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

**Are you working only with square images ?**

I updated your code and didn't try it, but it should work :

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_sport" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView02"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_science" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView03"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_science" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView04"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_sport" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout03"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView05"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_sport" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView06"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_science" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: if you're using `layout_weight` you should put `0dp` for either the `layout_height` or `layout_width` depending on which you want it to effect.

Comment: All my images are square yes, i only need it to work with Square images

Comment: Your code doesn't work :( they go back to touching vertically but with big gaps horizonally